# Computer Science maths - graphs and trees

Tags: graph-theory, trees

> Let $x_1, x_2, . . . , x_n$ be the leaves of a tree $T$. Let $d_{ij}$ be the length of the
>   unique path $P_{ij}$ between $x_i$ and $x_j$
>   . For any four distinct indices $i$, $j$, $k$ and $l$, show that if
>   $P_{ij}$ and $P_{kl}$ have no vertices in common, then:
>
> $d_{ij} + d_{kl} < d_{ik} + d_{jl} = d_{il} + d_{jk}$

I don't even know how to start this

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Thats the problem i don't know how to start

Comment: Try drawing a picture.

Comment: @Master: If it were me, I would try drawing some trees and try to figure out what the problem was saying.  That might help figure out where to start.

Comment: This is a really nice exercise. As usual, a good way to get started is to try and solve an easier problem: try the case when $d_{ij}=2$, make a picture, and use the fact that there is a *unique* path between two vertices

Answer (score 1):

A hint:

The path $P_{ij}$ contains $\geq2$ vertices $q_r$, and the path $P_{kl}$ contains $\geq2$ vertices $q_r'$. Among all paths connecting a $q_r$ with a $q_r'$ there is a shortest one. It has length $\geq1$ and connects a vertex $q\in P_{ij}$ with a vertex $q'\in P_{kl}$.